# MailChimp (Mandrill) for .NET why email includes Image?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm using MailChimp for .NET from this nuget https://www.nuget.org/packages/mcapi.net/1.3.1.3 and tried sending emails. But the email I received include image (unseen image) even if I'm just sending simple html. Has anyone encountered it? How to get rid of this unseen image? Please help.

Below is my sample email message.

```
var api = new MandrillApi("XXXXXXXXXXX");
var recipients = new List<Mandrill.Messages.Recipient>();
var name = string.Format("{0} {1}", "Jobert", "Enamno");
recipients.Add(new Mandrill.Messages.Recipient("recipient@gmail.com", name));
var message = new Mandrill.Messages.Message()
{
   To = recipients.ToArray(),
   FromEmail = "admin@mysite.com",
   Subject = "Test Email",
   Html = "<div>Test</div>"
};
MVList<Mandrill.Messages.SendResult> result;
result = api.Send(message);
```

**Received Email**
[image]

**When clicked No image shown**

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're seeing this because Mandrill uses a small invisible graphic for open tracking.  You'd want to either disable open tracking in the API call you're making or on the [Sending Options](https://mandrillapp.com/settings/sending-options) page in your Mandrill account.

Comment: Please suggest me how to send Mandrill template using c#.

Comment: how to add global_merge_vars tag in message, please help me.